# User replace value in string array with a new value

Tags: c#, arrays

Need some help with user input in array. I've created a string array with 5 elements. User types in 5 names and program prints them.

I want the user to type an index and then a new name. Program should print out all the names again but now with the new name instead of the old one on that index.

```
            Console.WriteLine("Type in 5 names: ");


            string[] input = new string[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {

                input[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                int rank = i + 1;
                Console.WriteLine(rank + ". " + input[i]);
            }
```

Here I'm suppose to ask user for index (name) to replace, and a name to replace the old one with. But I just can't figure out the code. (I know how to ask but not the code replacing the names).

Comment: Your so close - if you think about the code to set the initial value is really just the same code for replacing a value in the array you have declared. The first time you are replacing the empty value with a name.

Comment: Showing what you've tried on the specific problem you're asking about and what didn't work will probably go a long way to helping you get an answer that helps you better understand why it didn't work rather than a question asking people to solve the whole problem for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type in 5 names: ");

    string[] input = new string[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        input[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    Print(input);

    Console.WriteLine("Choose an index: ");
    int index = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Type new name: ");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    input[index - 1] = name;

    Print(input);
}

void Print(string[] names) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        int rank = i + 1;
        Console.WriteLine(rank + ". " + names[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant an index based on your rank. That's why i used "index - 1"